# How do I copy all cookies from a WebBrowser class and put them in a CookieCollection?

Tags: c#, web-applications

The title pretty much stands for itself. But I am using an HTTPWebRequest to download pages from the internet, but these pages require a login, so you log in with the WebBrowser and it uses the resulting cookies to be able to download the actual page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create (myUri);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer ();
request.CookieContainer.SetCookies (myUri, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);
```

---

**Edit:** For your case, you may consider a NetworkCredential Object. It will work perfectly without any need for a WebBrowser or Cookies.

```
 WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
    NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
    myWebRequest.Credentials = networkCredential;
```

Comment: I already came across the first code there, and when I run it, it comes up with a "StackOverflowExeption" and points to the foreach loop. And this requires the user to use there own info, and I would just prefer to do it through the webbrowser. Lastly, this is a program to view all of the info of a player on xbox.com, does that require any special cookie stuff to have it do this with the xbox website?

Comment: It's the URL you will be using for your web request. It's pretty unexplainable.!!!!

Comment: Pointed to:     container.SetCookies(new Uri("http://login.live.com"), form1.webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);                with the error:   "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"